# How do I move a Wordpress page up a directory level?

Tags: wordpress

Part of our website is Wordpress.  We have had a text blog page at ourdomain.com/blog/ for a long time.  We have added a separate videos only page at ourdomain.com/blog/videos/   Now that the videos page is finished they want to move it to ourdomain.com/videos  (the text blog would stay in the same place.)  How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

use rewrite rules.

e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^videos/(.*)$ /blog/videos/$1 [L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: do i put this in: wp-includes/rewrite.php?

Comment: No, you have to put it into the .htaccess file of root of your web tree. Have a look, there is a .htaccess file in your wordpress folder. If you want to handle the directory level above, you have to handle this in an .htaccess file in that very directory ...

Comment: please note the "e.g." depending on your environment you might need to tweak it, you might even need to enable it first e.g. "RewriteEngine on" ... please check the documentation link above